# Vitess Sharding issue

Tags: vitess, kubernetes-vitess

I am new to the Vitess and we have deployed Vitess in Kubernetes using Helm Charts and exposed VTGate through node Port and able to connect MYSQL Work bench using the exposed VTGate Ip Address.
When we inserted the records using MySql Work Bench, Records are not scattering across the Shards.

```
  * 'Payrolls' is the KeySpace and we created two shards as Payrolls -80,Payrolls 80-.

  * Table Schema as below

     1. TenantList
        (
           TenantID     INT,
           NAme      VARCHAR(200)
        )  


     2.  PayrollMaster
        (
          PayrollID   INT PRIMARY KEY,
          HHAID       INT FOREIGN KEY TO TenantList(TenantID)
        )  

     3. PayrollDetails
       (
         PayrollDetailID    INT PRIMARY KEY,
         PayrollID          INT FOREIGN KEY TO PayrollMaster(PayrollID),
         HHAID              INT FOREIGN KEY TO TenantList(TenantID)
       )

   *   VSchema is as below
      {
       "sharded": true,
       "vindexes": {
        "hash": {
         "type": "hash"
        }
     },
    "tables": {
     "payrollmaster": {
     "column_vindexes": 
      [
       {
         "column": "HHA",
         "name": "hash"
       }
      ],
      "auto_increment": {
       "column": "PayrollInternalID",
       "sequence": "payrollmaster_seq"
      }
    },
    "payrolldetails": {
     "column_vindexes": 
     [
       {
         "column": "HHA",
         "name": "hash"
       }
     ],
     "auto_increment": {
       "column": "PayrollDetailInternalID",
       "sequence": "payrolldetails_seq"
     }
   }
 }
}


    We are inserting the Records like below
      use Payrolls;
      insert into the TenantList,PayrollMaster,PayrollDetails
```

We are expecting the Records to be scattered across the Shards but table has zero rows in the Shards.

[image: Key Space and Shards were created as mentioned in the screenshot]

is there any issue with the way we are trying.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want payrolls to be sharded. If so, you shouldn't create a shard "0". You should only specify shards "-80" and "80-"

Comment: Thanks @sugu Sougoumarane. We have followed  the vitess/302_new_shards.yaml to create new shards and shard was created for keyspace/0. What is the advantage of creating a shard for keyspace/0. if we select a key which is a foreign key to all the tables then all the referenced tables will shard automatically?

Comment: The sharding scheme is specified in the vschema. The distribution of rows in various shards is decided by the primary vindex you choose: https://vitess.io/docs/reference/vschema/. Vitess doesn't recommend or support cross-shard foreign keys because of efficiency reasons. You should design your vschema to keep FK relationships within shard.

Comment: I have Updated the VSchema. Can you Please check. we have mentioned the vindexes but data was not sharded automatically.

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane In the helm example of planet scale shard 0 also is there
https://github.com/planetscale/vitess/blob/master/examples/helm/302_new_shards.yaml
In this case queries to direct VTGate won't work?

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in vschema? The primary vindex for both tables is "HHA", but I don't see the columns in the table schema. In the example shard 0 exists first, then we reshard that into -80 and 80. After resharding, shard 0 will be deleted.

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane we deleted the Shard 0 and now we are getting the error while connecting mysql from work bench or Application. Error : "No partition found for tabletType master in keyspace payrolls" . are we missing anything?

Comment: @ChethanSR If you add shards, you have to go through the resarding workflow to migrate data from the original shard to the new ones. You can delete the source shard only after you cutover the traffic. The example shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SuguSougoumarane. We followed the below steps to delete the shard 0.

First we did SplitClone -min_healthy_rdonly_tablets=1 payrolls/0

then migrated like
MigrateServedTypes payrolls/0 rdonly
MigrateServedTypes payrolls/0 replica
MigrateServedTypes payrolls/0 master
DeleteShard -recursive payrolls/0.

are we missing anything? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks right. I'm wondering if one of those steps failed. We've rehearsed those steps multiple times. There are also online demos that I presented at Kubecon that show that they work. If you have the logs, can you see if there are errors?